# CreateFile path error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        sprintf_s(text, "Text from process %d\r\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\dev\\test\\test.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            cout << "Error opening file " << GetLastError() << " at index " << i << endl;
            break;
        }
        SetFilePointer(hFile, GetFileSize(hFile, NULL), NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        DWORD bytes;
        WriteFile(hFile, text, strlen(text), &bytes, NULL);


        CloseHandle(hFile);


    }
```

i'm trying to open write using the actual device name 
\Device\HarddiskVolume2 is mapped to c:\
the folder already exist in c drive
i'm getting error opening file

Comment: can you please explain what is a error?

Comment: error opening file 3 at index 0

Comment: A bit more caring about Capital letter at the beginning, using of commas etc., and people are more likely to take a question serious.

Answer (score 2):

Error code 3 is [`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND). The reason you see that is because `\\.\Device\HarddiskVolume2` is the path of the raw device. If you use that path, you no longer have access to the file system. What that path gives you is access to the raw disk sectors.

If you must use `\\.\Device\HarddiskVolume2` to identify the drive then you need to first convert, by some means or other, to a mapped drive letter, or a DOS device path for the volume. The latter would be, in your case, `\\.\HarddiskVolume2`

Comment: i just removed the prefix \\device from CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\HarddiskVolume2\\dev\\test\\test.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
now its writing to "c:\dev\test\test.txt"

Comment: why u have to write \\ twice

Comment: Because \ is the escape character in C++ literals and so needs to be escaped itself.

Comment: why u need to identify the drive c:\ is symbolic link to HardDiskVolume2 in my PC

Comment: I don't understand that question

Comment: You don't need to use a drive letter, you can access files via the path to the file system device.  For example, if your C drive is on volume 2, `dir \\.\HarddiskVolume2\windows` will work.  The confusion arises from the fact that `\\.` doesn't point to the root of the kernel's object hierarchy but to the so-called MS-DOS device namespace, `\DosDevices`.  So the correct path is `\\.\HarddiskVolume2` rather than `\\.\Device\HarddiskVolume2`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please  refer 
[ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
3 (0x3)
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

So please try to check the path is available or not `..\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\dev\\test\\test.txt`.
this is because program unable to find the path

or try this:

`..\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\dev\\test\\test.txt`
if the path is in same directory as your exe.

**Reason**

While creating the file the compiler look into the path which is in the directory where the `exe` file is. If it is not found then Program will check into the `Drive` where the Program is running.

Also try to get some information from [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't think you've really understood any of this. The path in the question is absolute. Your prepending of ..\ makes it relative, but the .. is parent directory. Of course none of it helps because the asker wants to name a specific disk volume.